# show date on axis of a plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question. I want to plot an graph in matplotlib. The x-axis contains dates and the y-axis heights in meters above see level. From my readin method i get.

minlist = [368.23000000000002, 368.12, 368.20999999999998, 368.35000000000002, 368.16000000000003, 367.98000000000002, 367.98000000000002, 367.97000000000003, 367.83999999999997, 367.63999999999999, 367.85000000000002, 367.56, 367.87, 367.99000000000001, 367.75, 367.88, 367.92000000000002, 367.81, 367.86000000000001, 367.95999999999998, 367.79000000000002, 367.67000000000002, 367.81999999999999, 367.91000000000003, 367.81999999999999, 367.81999999999999, 367.74000000000001, 367.80000000000001, 367.76999999999998, 367.85000000000002, 367.88999999999999, 367.76999999999998, 367.79000000000002, 367.86000000000001, 367.88999999999999, 367.86000000000001, 367.94999999999999, 367.94999999999999, 367.87, 367.91000000000003]

this list should have two digits after the comma.

Now i used a method to convert strings like '23.05.2012' to date.

```
def stringtodate(array):

i = 1
end = len(array)

date_format = []

while i <= end:

    string_date = str(array[i-1])

    time_tuple = datetime.strptime(string_date, "%d.%m.%Y")

    date_format.append(time_tuple)

    i = i+1

return date_format
```

that returns a list like that:

yearlist = [datetime.datetime(1975, 7, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1976, 11, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1977, 9, 23, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1978, 7, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1979, 7, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1980, 9, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1981, 8, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1982, 7, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1983, 9, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1984, 8, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1985, 9, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1986, 9, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1987, 8, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1988, 8, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1989, 7, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1990, 7, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1991, 7, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1992, 7, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1993, 8, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1994, 8, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1995, 7, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1996, 8, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1997, 8, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1998, 8, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2000, 5, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2001, 8, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2002, 8, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2004, 10, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2005, 7, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2006, 5, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2007, 9, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 5, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 1, 0, 0)]

now i want to plot these two lists with matplotlib. My code is:

```
def plotminimum(minList,yearList):

print(minList)
print(yearList)

try:

    plt.xlabel('Datum')
    plt.ylabel('minimale Sohle [m.u.A]')


    plt.xticks(yearList)
    plt.xticks(rotation=70)

    plot(yearList,minList, label='blau')

    show()

except:

    print('Profil nicht vorhanden!')
```

The problem now is the x-axis doesnt show the date. I cant find my mistake alone, please help me.

I hope i provided you with enough information to help me solve the problem.

greetings

Comment: the x-axis shows a number with 6 digits instead. unfortunately i cant post the plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I converted the date within the graphing program. I had a series with the dates pulled straight from a csv file, so the dates originally looked like 10/2/2014. I named that series date. My code looks like this:

```
date = data['Date'] # data is just the variable I am using to hold the csv file. 
# The above line is just pulling the date column into it's own variable.

x1 = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y').date() for d in date]
```

You will have to add a line in your imports to import datetime as dt for this to work. Then, when you use the plot command, set it up like this:

```
plot(x1, minList, label='blau')
```

This should properly label the x-axis without the need for the plt.xticks(yearList), but if you can try it with and without.

Comment: That would work, yes! But the problem is i want the date of my list displayed at the x-axis. Deleting plt.xticks(yearList) causes matplotlib to scale the x-axis automatically but this is not what i need.

Comment: Hmm.... I dug through my graphing programs and it looks like I did something similar to you. The main difference is that I didn't convert the date prior to the graphing program. I will update my answer with how I wrote my graphing programs out and you can see if that helps.

Comment: your code works just as my method! The problem is i get a print on the x-achsis that looks like 721191. I googled it and it prints the number counted fom the gregorian calender or something like that.

Comment: That is odd. Sorry, I don't know why it would do that. What exactly do the dates look like before you re-format them?

Comment: Ok, this is the last thing I can think to try. Replace the line `plt.xticks(yearList)` with `plt.xticks(range(len(minList)), yearList)` and change the line `plot(yearList,minList, label='blau')` with `plot(minList, label='blau')`